# Update table in stored procedure with the new data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure which I pass 3 parameters to, and exports the whole thing in this table, let's call it `dbo.myFinalTable`. I want to achieve two things:

Task #1:

I need to append data when i'm executing the procedure again with any parameters I'm passing.

I tried adding this at the end of my final table creation, but the total number of rows stays the same. What is there to be done?

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myDatabase' 
              AND TABLE_NAME = 'dbo.myFinalTable'))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.myFinalTable
       SELECT
           someValues 
       FROM #tempInWhichIcalulate
       ORDER BY someOtherStuff
END
```

Task #2:

I execute it like this:

```
execute [myStoredProcedure] 'someString', '123', '2013-03-14'
```

I want the query above to only append data if the columns `id` and `theDate` (from `dbo.MyFinalTable`; those columns have their data passed from the stored procedure, in this example values `'123'`, `'2013-03-14'`) don't have those values already there.

Note: my procedure declaration looks like this:

```
alter procedure [myStoredProcedure]
    (@theString varchar (30),
     @id varchar (10),
     @theDate date)
```

Comment: Hello, Can you post the results of the `dbo.FinalTable` ? @CM2K

Comment: the important columns are `theDate` and `id` , rest of them are just some values calculated. Can't post my real table

Comment: And is this your stored procedure `alter procedure [myStoredProcedure]
(
@theString varchar (30),
@id varchar (10),
@theDate date
)` @CM2K

Comment: but there is no query in your stored procedure? There are only variables. There is no `Select statement` which uses the variables. @CM2K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your goal, this could be the query:

```
insert into dbo.myFinalTable
select
@theString as MyString,
@id as MyId,
@theDate as MyDate
where not exists(select * from dbo.myFinalTable 
                 where MyId = @id
                 and MyDate = @theDate)
```